# mssql select with LIKE utf-8 - Cyrillic_General_CI_AS

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm working with PHP/MSSQL all select queries work fine, but when I try to SELECT with LIKE '%строка%' it doesn't retrieve any data - PHP files in utf8 and MSSQL in Cyrillic_General_CI_AS? 
Please help, there weren't any forums helpful.

Comment: Can you add the table definition please?

Comment: What is the collation of the column that you are looking at? Without the table definition we will not be able to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify the collation in the query. It is hard to figure out from your question what the correct collation is, but this will give you the idea.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS LIKE '%строка%'
```